# Directories user choice interfaces with Wix

Tags: wix

I am a new user with fantastic Wix system; Here is my trouble . I don t understant how I can make for have two selectors in a double directory user selector. My code (.wks) is abble for user to select one directory . But I want that the system prelted to select one for program components and a second to install a working directory user choice . Here is my code .

http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>

```
<Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer'
  Description="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installer"
  Comments='Foobar is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'
  InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

<Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
<Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installation [1]" />

<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
<Directory Id="WindowsFolder" Name="Windows">
    <Directory Id="WindowsSystem32" Name="System32">
      <Component Id="ApplicationDll" Guid="45645678-1234-1234-1234-782222222222">
        <File Id="ApplicationFile7" Source="BolosData\dll\Bol_Dll.dll" />
        <File Id="ApplicationFile8" Source="BolosData\dll\libBol_Dll.dll.a" />
        <File Id="ApplicationFile9" Source="BolosData\dll\libBol_Dll.dll.def" />
        <File Id="ApplicationFile10" Source="BolosData\dll\mingwm10.dll" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
    <Directory Id='Acme' Name='Acme'>
      <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Foobar 1.0'>

        <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='12345678-83F1-4F22-985B-FDB3C8ABD471'>
          <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1' Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
            <Shortcut Id="startmenuFoobar10" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
            <Shortcut Id="desktopFoobar10" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Foobar 1.0" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
          </File>
        </Component>

        <Component Id='HelperLibrary' Guid='12345678-6BE3-460D-A14F-75658D16550B'>
          <File Id='HelperDLL' Name='Helper.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Helper.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='Manual' Guid='12345678-574D-4A9A-A266-5B5EC2C022A4'>
          <File Id='Manual' Name='Manual.pdf' DiskId='1' Source='Manual.pdf' KeyPath='yes'>
            <Shortcut Id="startmenuManual" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Instruction Manual" Advertise="yes" />
          </File>
        </Component>

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0">
      <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="12345678-7E98-44CE-B049-C477CC0A2B00">
        <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
</Directory>

<Feature Id='Complete' Title='Title 5001' Description='The complete package.'
  Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>


  <Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Program 5002' Description='The main executable.' Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
    <ComponentRef Id='HelperLibrary' />
    <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id='Documentation' Title='Description 5003' Description='The instruction manual.' Level='1000'>
    <ComponentRef Id='Manual' />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id='Dll' Title='Description 5004' Description='The Dll et C++ runtimes.' Level='1000'>
    <ComponentRef Id='ApplicationDll' />
  </Feature>
</Feature>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

<Icon Id="Foobar10.exe" SourceFile="FoobarAppl10.exe" />
```

and here is my batch command line:

```
@echo off
candle %1.wxs
light -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:fr-fr -dWixUILicenseRtf=D:\chinoi\BolosData\Res\bolosRd_intro.rtf %1.wixobj -out %1.msi
```

If someone can help me ...

Comment: Are you trying to customize the UI to set 2 directories?

Comment: No, because I dont know how i can do that . I am a Wix user 15 days ago. I am progressing with 'littles arms'. It seems to me that documentation is a little bit obscurius . Bref, if you have examples or links i am verry interrested because if C or ++ or VB it goes right if xml or declarative langage i am not a champion. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain again what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So with a part my code  .wxs. We can see TARGETDIR diretory who's deal with the selector <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR">INSTALLDIR</Property> all my programm files. But there are the dll and mingw files to install. I want that users can choose the install directory with a dialog box.

Comment: How can i add a second selector for the system32 directory (dll and so ...) ?

Comment: The documentation is obscure because WiX is a toolset for building Windows Installer packages, which are databases. The WiX documentation usually links back to the Windows Installer documentation. And, UI customizations (beyond the designed parameters), are not so common.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set a new directory property and pass it threw the UI Installdir dialog.

Download the source code of wix and copy WixUI_Mondo.wxs to your project.
Do the same for InstallDirDlg.wxs.

Edit and rename them both.

Check this tutorial for editing dialog.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

In the installdir dialog you will have to add almost the same section as:

```
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Hope it will get you to right direction.

Comment: Hello with low speed I try to understand the princeps of the manipulation. I work . Thanks for the tips. Perhaps could we not use two repertory selectors ... I going round and round tutorials ....